# data type varchar to float in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an error in my SQL Server database

> Error converting data type `varchar` to float.

My table is below here. And I want the solution for this.

Error is on the line

```
ROUND(REPLACE(CalvedF,''*'',''''),0) AS [Calved]
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NonPedigreeBovinesDairy](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Upto3MonthsM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Over3monthsupto6monthsM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Over6monthsupto12monthsM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Over12monthsupto16monthsM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Over16monthsupto20monthsM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [months20andoverM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [upto3monthsF] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Over3monthsupto6monthsF] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [over6monthsupto12monthsF] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [over12monthsupto16monthsF] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [over16monthsupto20monthsF] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [months20andoverF] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [calvedF] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NonPedigreeBovinesDairy] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and procedure is:

```
if @CatId = 3          
Begin            

if @gender = 'Male'            
Begin          
SET @cmd = 'SELECT id, DATENAME(month,[Date]) + '' '' + CAST(YEAR([Date]) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Monthyear,           
Day([Date]) AS [DayNo],           
ROUND(REPLACE(Upto3MonthsM,''*'',''''),0) AS [Upto 3 Months],          
ROUND(REPLACE(Over3monthsupto6monthsM,''*'',''''),0) AS [Over 3 months upto 6months],          
ROUND(REPLACE(Over6monthsupto12monthsM,''*'',''''),0) AS [Over 6 months upto 12 months],           
ROUND(REPLACE(Over12monthsupto16monthsM,''*'',''''),0) AS [Over 12 months upto 16months],          
ROUND(REPLACE(Over16monthsupto20monthsM,''*'',''''),0) AS [Over 16 months upto 20 months],          
ROUND(REPLACE(months20andoverM,''*'',''''),0) AS [Months 20 and over]          
FROM NonPedigreeBovinesDairy WHERE CAST(YEAR([Date]) AS VARCHAR(4)) ='+@lastyears+''            
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd            
End          

if @gender = 'FeMale'            
Begin       
SET @cmd = 'SELECT id, DATENAME(month,[Date]) + '' '' + CAST(YEAR([Date]) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Monthyear,           
 Day([Date]) AS [DayNo],           
 ROUND(REPLACE(Upto3monthsF,''*'',''''),0) AS [Upto 3 months],          
 ROUND(REPLACE(Over3monthsupto6monthsF,''*'',''''),0) AS [Over 3 months upto 6 months],          
 ROUND(REPLACE(Over6monthsupto12monthsF,''*'',''''),0) AS [Over 6 months upto 12 months],
 ROUND(REPLACE(Over12monthsupto16monthsF,''*'',''''),0) AS [Over 12 months upto 16 months],          
 ROUND(REPLACE(Over16monthsupto20monthsF,''*'',''''),0) AS [Over 16 months upto 20 months],
 ROUND(REPLACE(CalvedF,''*'',''''),0) AS [Calved]          
 FROM NonPedigreeBovinesDairy WHERE CAST(YEAR([Date]) AS VARCHAR(4)) = '+@lastyears+''            
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd   
End          

End
```

Comment: Can you add some data to your question?

Comment: ROUND(REPLACE(CalvedF,''*'',''''),0) AS [Calved] .   I want add another replace for REPLACE(CalvedF,''-'',''''),0. Because I have an - data in my table.

Comment: ROUND should not accept varchar it expects a numeric value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) is there any special reason you use varchar to store float values?

Comment: What is the value on wich CASTING throws error !Because you could pass and cast varchar field to ROUND() function,maybe you didn't replace some cahracter?You could also use ISNUMERIC() function to check whether string is number

Comment: and why on earth are you using dynamic sql, it is totally unnneeded as fara as I can see. You are just making it harder to maintain the code by using it.